# Tensorflow - How to make a random squar tensor of 0 and 1 with a fixed number of 1 for each line

Tags: python, tensorflow, random

I'm looking to randomly build (without loop) a square tensor (e.g. shape=(N,N)) with the following properties:

- The tensor can only contain 0 and 1 values;
- The number of 1 is fixed for each line and is the same for each line (P the number of 1 for each line with P < N);
- The elements of the diagonal is necessarily a 0.

Can you help me?

Thank you

Romain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code. It is based on comparing elements with p-th maximum for every row.

```
import tensorflow as tf
N = 5
P = 2
rand = tf.random.uniform((N, N))
diag = tf.linalg.tensor_diag(tf.ones([N]))
rand -= diag # guarantees minimums for diagonal elements
cut_off, _ = tf.math.top_k(rand, P)
cut_off = tf.reduce_min(cut_off, axis=-1, keepdims=True) # p-th max for every row
output = tf.greater_equal(rand, cut_off)
output = tf.cast(output, tf.int32)
```